# Deleting duplicate records based on two columns concatenation values

Tags: plsql

I have a table employee has 30000 records. I need to delete duplicate records based on two columns concatenation. For example name and job, like

```
martin clerk
martin clerk
```

Below is my code:

```
declare
    type typ_emp is table of emp%rowtype;

    v_emp   typ_emp;

    cursor cur_emp
    is
          select *
            from emp a
           where rowid >
                     (select min (rowid)
                        from emp b
                       where concat (concat (b.ename, '-'), b.job) =
                             concat (concat (a.ename, '-'), a.job)
                     )
               ;
begin
    open cur_emp;

    loop
        fetch cur_emp bulk collect into v_emp;

        exit when v_emp.count = 0;

        if v_emp.count > 0
        then
           for i in v_emp.first .. v_emp.last
           loop
               insert into backup_emp (ename, job)
               values (v_emp (i).ename, v_emp (i).job)
                    ;
           end loop;
        end if;
    end loop;

    close cur_emp;

    delete
      from emp s
     where s.rowid >
              any (select t.rowid
                     from emp t
                    where concat (concat (t.ename, '-'), t.job) =
                             concat (concat (s.ename, '-'), s.job));

    commit;
exception
    when others then
        Raise;
end;
```

It is taking a long time to delete the records. Can anyone help me in tuning a query for this or suggest me what is the better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating function based index might improve your performance

```
 CREATE INDEX concatindex ON emp (ename||'-'||job);
```

Delete statement would look like this

```
delete emp a where a.rowid > (select min(rowid) from emp b where b.ename||'-'||b.job=a.ename||'-'||a.job)
```

unless you need to insert deleted rows into backup table which is not clear from your question. If so I would rather bulkcollect rows into collection. Leave a comment if you need to have detailed this option.

Comment: Hi Mina, Thanks for reply.I have solved my problem using analytical function row_number() where i have used cursor to select duplicate rows.It improved the performanace a lot before it is taking 6 min to complete the task now only 40sec.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code changes:

```
cursor cur_emp
    is
          select *
            from 
            (select b.*
                   ,row_number()over(partition by concat (concat (b.ename, '-'), b.job) order by ename)cnt
             from emp b                       
                     ) where cnt>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
SELECT ROWID, ename || '-' || job AS concatenation,
       decode(rank() over(PARTITION BY ename || '-' || job ORDER BY ROWID), 1, 'keep', 'delete') AS to_do
  FROM emp
 ORDER BY ename || '-' || job, ROWID;
```